# Selecting subsets of field to generate new field in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

Aside from using code in the field calculator, how can one create a new field to have values based on another field?

For example I have a built-in field already which contains 0s and 1s and I want my new field to have 100 where that built-in field has 0 and 200 where the built-in has 1.

Comment: Add new field then two times: Select by attributes - Field calculator. Or are you asking for a solution without using Field Calculator at all?

Comment: @BERA I tried that method but must be doing something wrong... can you go into detail so I can troubleshoot?.

Comment: (Oldfield+1)×100

Comment: ok what if instead of 0s and 1s you had y and n

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, I would always do this using the Python Parser of the Field Calculator but in the old days there was a method that should still work.

You could create and populate a table (often referred to as a lookup table) with two fields and two rows:

```
FieldA FieldB
0      100
1      200
```

and then use the [Join Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/join-field.htm) tool to join new field FieldB onto the table using the common field of FieldA.

That tool:

> Joins the contents of a table to another table based on a common
>   attribute field. The input table is updated to contain the fields from
>   the join table. You can select which fields from the join table will
>   be added to the input table.

Comment: +1 For simplicity of the solution and the old days.

Comment: @User2009 I *think* its predecessor JOINITEMS was one the first 32 tools in ARC/INFO and there is a Q&A here where someone refers to Join Field as a new tool.

Answer (score 2):

note that, in your case, this could be done by simple arithmetic :

```
!newfield! = (!oldfield!+1)*100
```

EDIT based on comment on x and y instead of 0 and 1.

@PolyGeo 's answer is more generic. Alternatively, using a code in the field calculator (or in a Python script) would be faster (to write and to run).

Codeblock

```
dict = {'x':100,'y':200}
def LookUpTable(fld):
    return dict.get(fld,-1) #-1 is the default value in case the key does not exist in the dictionnary
```

newfield =

```
LookUpTable(!OldFieldName!)
```

Comment: +1 because similarly to this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186393/field-calc-to-change-one-digit-in-a-sequence-arcmap/186401#186401 pre-school math  is effective tool.

Comment: Thanks @FelixIP . I just see that you had mentioned it in your comment when I was writing my answer. Sorry if I took your idea. Next time I suggest that you write an answer immediately. i've upvoted your other answer.